# Node_modules copying takes too much while generating a war

Tags: javascript, java, maven, node-modules, war

I working on a project which uses node. There is node_modules folder present in the project's webapp directory. Now the problem is when I do maven build to generate war file, it tries to copy the node_module folder into the war file which not only makes the war files size huge but also takes 25 mins at this step. Also while deploying this war file with node_modules in tomcat it takes lot of time. 
Is there a better way to do it? I know I can skip copying of node_modules folder into my war but will the war work when deployed on server without node_modules in it?

Comment: You should use something like `webpack` and build a dist.js file with all the relevant code for you application, not including the whole node_modules folder. Please take a look at https://medium.com/@jsilvax/introducing-webpack-into-an-existing-java-based-web-app-ff53f14d37ec

Comment: Thanks for the response Pablo, I can't make too many changes with webpack at this stage, not sure if that's allowed to be used in the project... That's different story.